# How can I create multiple boxplots with seaborn using cuts of data from the same dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, data-science

I currently have a dataframe which contains different stores and scores associated with each store. Each row represents one set of scores from a specific time period, so each store is represented multiple times in the dataset. I want to build a series of boxplots, one for each store, and show the spread of each score, for that specific score.

So far, the only approach I am confident will work is to create new filtered data frames, then individually boxplot each of those dataframes. However, I feel like there is a more elegant solution, perhaps involving a for loop, where I don't have to manually build each separate data frame.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('Store_scores.csv')


df_storeA = df.loc['Store_A',:]
df_storeB = df.loc['Store_B',:]
df_storeC = df.loc['Store_C',:]

sns.boxplot(data=df_storeA, y=values, x=categories)
sns.boxplot(data=df_storeB, y=values, x=categories)
sns.boxplot(data=df_storeC, y=values, x=categories)
```

While this technically works, there are several stores within the dataset, so I'd love something a little less manual, and a little more robust.

Comment: Would you please provide a representation of your DataFrame? Or, even better, give us a few lines of code that show how to make it ourselves (if just with dummy data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your values and categories don't change you can use a for loop like you mentioned

```
df = pd.read_csv('Store_scores.csv')

#removes duplicates
stores = set(df.index)

#iterate over the stores and plot
for store in stores:    
    sns.boxplot(data=df.loc[store,:], y=values, x=categories)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears your data maintains an index on store, consider creating a column out of it and include it as the *hue* in one call of `seaborn.boxplot` (assuming *categories* are a manageable, handful size):

```
df = df.reset_index()
sns.boxplot(data=df, x="categories", y="values", hue="index")
```

---

To demonstrate with random, seeded data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(72319)
random_df = (pd.DataFrame({'categories': np.random.choice(['julia', 'python', 'r'], 500),
                          'values': np.random.uniform(50, 100, 500),                         
                         }, index = np.random.choice(['Store_A', 'Store_B', 'Store_C'], 500))
               .sort_index())

random_df = random_df.reset_index()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,5))
sns.boxplot(data=random_df, x="categories", y="values", hue="index", ax=ax)

plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

[image: Plot Output]